# Opportunity Sharing Rule creation option not available

Tags: apex, opportunity, security, sharing, sharing-rule

In one of my org I changed the OWD for Opportunity from **Public Read Only** to **Private**.

However, I can't see the option to create a new sharing rule for Opportunity. What could be the possible reason for this?

**Option for Opportunity:**
[image]

**Option for Account:**

[image: Option For Account]

Comment: Did you wait for a while after changing the OWD? Usually it takes some time for the change to get reflected in the org.

Comment: Yes, Even now also I can't see it

Comment: convert Account/Contact to Private OWD and then use sharing rules to extend access to Account/Contact to all internal users